# Doctrine2 usando composer erro de namespace

Tags: php, doctrine, namespace

Olá estou criando um arquivo que serve como base class em Entidades\BaseTable.php como segue:

```
<?php namespace Entidades;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @MappedSuperclass
 */
class BaseTable
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="datetime")
     * @var datetime
     */
    protected $criado_em;

    public function __construct()
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne');
        $this->criado_em = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
?>
```

O outro arquivo é um extend do base, que está em Entidades\Sistema\Aplicativo.php como segue:

```
<?php namespace Entidades\Sistema;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="sistema.aplicativos")
 */
class Aplicativo Extends \Entidades\BaseTable
{
    /**
     * @Column(type="string", nullable=false)
     * @var string
     */
    public $nome;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", unique=true, nullable=false)
     * @var string
     */
    public $app_key;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", unique=true, nullable=false)
     * @var string
     */
    public $esquema;

    public function addAplicativo($nome,$esquema)
    {
        $this->nome = $nome;
        $this->esquema = $esquema;
    }

    protected function newGuid()
    {
        if (function_exists('com_create_guid') === true)
        {
            return trim(com_create_guid(), '{}');
        }
        return sprintf('%04X%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X%04X%04X', mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(16384, 20479), mt_rand(32768, 49151), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535));
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->app_key = newGuid();
    }
}
?>
```

Ao rodar o comando "php vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create" pelo command tudo funciona certinho, sem problemas, as tabelas são criadas e etc...

Porem ao rodar um php como o exemplo abaixo:

```
<?php
require_once "bootstrap.php";

$novo = new Sistema\Aplicativo();
$novo->nome = 'Teste';
$novo->esquema = 'Teste';

$entityManager->persist($novo);
$entityManager->flush();

echo "Aplicativo com o ID " . $product->getId() . " criado com sucesso.\n";
?>
```

Recebo o seguinte erro em PHP:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Entidades\BaseTable' not found in APPPATH\Entidades\Sistema\Aplicativo.php on line 9
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0005  127704  {main}( )   ..\addAplicativo.php:0
2   0.0625  2090808 Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass( ) ..\addAplicativo.php:0
3   0.0625  2090912 Composer\Autoload\includeFile( )    ..\ClassLoader.php:274
4   0.0632  2098568 include( 'D:\TRABALHO\Admin v3\Server\Entidades\Sistema\Aplicativo.php' )   ..\ClassLoader.php:382
```

Como podem ver o arquivo do Aplicativo.php está incluído , consigo encontra-lo sem problemas, o problema é pegar o extend dele... Não sei porque isso está acontecendo, mas não consigo corrigir nem por reza, procurei alguns exemplos similares na internet e por ajuda em vários sites, mas nada que se relaciona-se a isso, creio que estou fazendo alguma burrada das grotescas... grato pela atenção.

Comment: Você já tentou colocar as duas entidades no mesmo namespace ?

Comment: Mesmo erro... tentei colocando a classe na mesma pasta e no mesmo namespace, em arquivos diferentes é claro... Dá o mesmo erro... É como se o autoloader não consegui-se carregar o arquivo BaseTable.php

Comment: Você poderia colocar o seu arquivo composer.json na perguntar para eu poder te ajudar ?

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUCIONADO**

O problema era com o composer autoload...

Eu fiz um erro bobo, a solução era colocar o psr-4 ao invez do psr-0 no autoload do composer, após alterar o psr-0 para psr-4 funcionou tudo 100%m segue a solução...

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "Entidades/",
        "Entidades\\": "Entidades/",
        "Entidades\\Sistema\\": "Entidades/Sistema/"
    }
}
```

Grato pela atenção pessoal.